# What configure fault?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, pacemaker, corosync, stonith

We hace a cluster two nodes with 2 resources, elastic-ip and nginx, and when we run crm_verify -LV

> error: unpack_operation:     Specifying on_fail=fence and stonith-enabled=false makes no sense
> error: unpack_operation:     Specifying on_fail=fence and stonith-enabled=false makes no sense
>
> Errors found during check: config not valid
>
> root@ip-172-31-18-143:~#

The configuration:

```
Cluster Name: hacluster
Corosync Nodes:
 ip-172-31-18-143 ip-172-31-27-85
Pacemaker Nodes:
 ip-172-31-18-143 ip-172-31-27-85

Resources:
 Resource: elastic-ip (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=awseip)
  Attributes: elastic_ip=***[MY_IP]*** allocation_id=" eipalloc-0xxxxxxxxxx" awscli=/usr/local/bin/aws
  Meta Attrs: migration-threshold=3 failure-timeout=60s
  Operations: start interval=0s timeout=10s on-fail=restart (elastic-ip-start-interval-0s)
              monitor interval=10s timeout=10s on-fail=restart (elastic-ip-monitor-interval-10s)
              stop interval=0s on-fail=fence (elastic-ip-stop-interval-0s)
 Resource: proxy (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=nginx)
  Attributes: configfile=/data_proxy/nginx/nginx.conf
  Meta Attrs: failure-timeout=60s
  Operations: start interval=0s timeout=40s (proxy-start-interval-0s)
              stop interval=0s on-fail=fence (proxy-stop-interval-0s)
              monitor interval=5s timeout=5s (proxy-monitor-interval-5s)

Stonith Devices:
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
  Resource: proxy
    Enabled on: ip-172-31-18-143 (score:50) (id:location-proxy-ip-172-31-18-143-50)
Ordering Constraints:
  start elastic-ip then start proxy (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-elastic-ip-proxy-mandatory)
Colocation Constraints:
  proxy with elastic-ip (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-proxy-elastic-ip-INFINITY)

Resources Defaults:
 migration-threshold: 2
Operations Defaults:
 No defaults set

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: corosync
 cluster-name: debian
 cluster-recheck-interval: 2min
 dc-version: 1.1.14-70404b0
 have-watchdog: false
 no-quorum-policy: ignore
 start-failure-is-fatal: true
 stonith-action: poweroff
 stonith-enabled: false
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/pcs", line 231, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/sbin/pcs", line 171, in main
    cmd_map[command](argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pcs/config.py", line 49, in config_cmd
    config_show(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pcs/config.py", line 86, in config_show
    cluster.cluster_uidgid([], True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pcs/cluster.py", line 1601, in cluster_uidgid
    uid_gid_files = os.listdir(settings.corosync_uidgid_dir)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/corosync/uidgid.d/'
root@ip-172-31-18-143:~#
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your resources (elastic-ip and proxy) and remove the attribute on_fail=fence , or enable Stonith as a cluster property and configure fencing.

Basically you are instructing the resource to fence a node when it fails but you have Stonith disabled so fencing is not possible (so it makes no sense)

Comment: But If we remove the attribute on_fail=fence the cluster will be able to balancing?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you mean